# C#, reflection, inheritence and static fields?

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection

I have a family of classes that inherit from an abstract superclass, which is implemented by two concrete classes:

```
public abstract class AbstractFoo 
{
    protected static string fooName = "Reset me!";

    public static string GetName()
    {
         return fooName;
    }
}
```

The subclasses are then constructed like

```
public class BarFoo : AbstractFoo 
{
    static BarFoo() 
    {
         fooName = "Pretty Name For BarFoo";
    }
}
```

and so forth.

I want to get a list of all the `AbstractFoo` implementations' pretty names so the user can decide which implementation to use.

My reflection code looks like

```
 Type fooType = typeof(AbstractFoo);

 List<Assembly> assemblies = new List<Assembly>(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

 IEnumerable<Type> allTypes = assemblies.SelectMany<Assembly, Type>(s => s.GetTypes());
 IEnumerable<Type> fooTypes = allTypes.Where(p => p.IsSubclassOf (fooType));

 foreach (Type thisType in fooTypes) 
 {
      MethodInfo method = thisType.GetMethod ("GetName", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
      string name = (string) method.Invoke (null, null);
  // add to the list, anyhow names.Add (name);  
  }
```

I end up with `method.Invoke` always returning "Rename Me" rather than the individual names.

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something silly here, but I'm not quite sure what.

Comment: `static` fields and methods aren't really "inherited". They're global (-ish) functions/variables whose namespace is the enclosing class, and this namespace is automatically accessible in the child classes.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm totally willing to rework how I store/retrieve the Name, as long as I can get this behavior (inspecting all implementing classes and assembling a list of their "prettyprint names.")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems.

First, your static field really isn't going to be doing what you want it to. There's *one* static field, in `AbstractFoo` - there isn't a separate `BarFoo.fooName` static field. So if you have a bunch of subclasses, whichever subclass gets type-initialized last will "win" in setting the field.

Next, when you invoke `BarFoo.GetName`, that's *really* just a call to `AbstractFoo.GetName` - `BarFoo` won't get initialized, so you won't see the "pretty name" being set.

Fundamentally, I suggest you redesign your code. I recommend that you decorate each class with an attribute. That way you won't end up relying on the type initializer at all, and you don't need to declare a separate static member for each type. The only downside is that the value has to be a constant...

An alternative is to use a virtual property which is then overridden in subclasses - although that requires you to create an instance of each type, of course.

Comment: Jon, given he implements your suggestion and uses a virtual property, would his reflection code need to raise an instance via Activator and invoke on the instance?  I.e., in order to let the runtime do its resolution algorithm?

Comment: @GarryVass: Yes, that would be required - which may well not be ideal. We don't really know what the aim is at the moment. I strongly suspect that attributes would be a better fit.

Comment: A "pretty name" for a class sounds like the textbook definition of metadata. I'd go with an attribute myself.

Comment: @millimoose: Yup - I've reordered my recommendations :)

Comment: Thank you Jon -- you're right that an Attribute solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is one copy of the static member. With your current setup, every subclass will overwrite that one copy, resulting in just one name being available. You need to make a static GetName function on every subclass and just return the name directly. I would recommend something along the lines of:

```
public abstract class AbstractFoo
{
}

public class BarFoo : AbstractFoo 
{
    public static string GetName()
    {
        return "Pretty Name For BarFoo";
    }
}

 Type fooType = typeof(AbstractFoo);
 List<Assembly> assemblies = new List<Assembly>(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
 IEnumerable<Type> allTypes = assemblies.SelectMany<Assembly, Type>(s => s.GetTypes());
 IEnumerable<Type> fooTypes = allTypes.Where(p => p.IsSubclassOf (fooType));
 foreach (Type thisType in fooTypes) 
 {

      MethodInfo method = thisType.GetMethod ("GetName", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
      string name = (string) method.Invoke (null, null);
  // add to the list, anyhow names.Add (name);  
  }
```

Another way to do it would be to keep a `Dictionary` as a static member in `AbstractFoo` and have the subclass' static initializers add something to that dictionary.